# How to sum the value of hashes in array with condition

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes like

```
records = [{"number"=>5000, "status"=>true},
           {"number"=>5000, "status"=>true},
           {"number"=>5000, "status"=>false}]
```

I want to sum the value of number whose status is `true`.

Comment: Show us your attempts.

Comment: To be fair to the OP, he did post his attempt (albeit in the comments) using `sum` but has since removed.

Comment: Does your array contain an arbitrary number of hashes, or exactly three? If the former, what is to be returned when `records` is an empty array? What do you want returned if  the value of `"status"` is `false` for all hashes`? Zero?  My point is that the statement of your question is incomplete. I suggest you edit to make the question complete and precise.

Comment: @TamerShlash, SO has no policy that requires askers to show "attempts" to solve the problem. If it's a homework problem (we don't know if this one is) evidence is to provided of attempts to solve the problem, but that does not necessarily mean code. Are you assuming this is a homework problem?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm not assuming anything and I'm not a "what have you tried" fan. But I think it depends on the question. We all know how hard it is to solve this in general and in Ruby, which is not so hard at all if you try. You may have mistakes in your solution, this is where SO is helpful for this type of questions. It's not SO's job to write _simple_ code for you or ask you to google it. If the question was a bit more complicated, the whole argument would be different. There's a thin line between being a no-attempt-nazi and turning SO into a code writing service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way using `sum`:

```
records.sum { |h| h["status"] ? h["number"] : 0 } #=> 10000
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much ,works !!
would you mind tell the what's the meaning of ": 0" you put there ?

Comment: @RayYu it's part of something called the ternary operator. It's like an if/else conditional but more compact: `if something_true ? do_this : otherwise_do_this`. Please look it up online. In this case it means if `h["status"]` is true add `h["number"]` to the sum otherwise if it's false add `0`. Sorry for the late reply but maybe your question and my reply will help someone else in the future.